# Potential Leak of Object stored into a NSMutable dictionary (GPUImageFramework) iOS 8+

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios8, xcode8, nsmutabledictionary

I am new to Objective C, and I would really appreciate any help resolving a memory leak. I am trying to resolve memory management issues that occur in the GPUImageFramework.

In the method below I am getting the following messages highlighted in blue:

- Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
- Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of+1

  ```
  -(void)setAndExecuteUniformStateCallbackAtIndex:(GLint)uniform forProgram:(GLProgram *)shaderProgram toBlock:(dispatch_block_t)uniformStateBlock;
  {
      [uniformStateRestorationBlocks setObject:[uniformStateBlock copy] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:uniform]];

      uniformStateBlock();

  }
  ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yfhu.jpg)

I take it that the method being stored in the NSMutable dictionary needs to be released into memory.

Please can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have ARC (automatic reference counting) enabled for your project or are you doing manual memory management (`release`, `retain`)?

Comment: I have ARC enabled within the GPUImageFramework.

Answer (score 0):

> I have ARC enabled within the GPUImageFramework

You either need to enable it for your project, not just for the framework, or you need to handle memory management manually.

The sub-expression `[uniformStateBlock copy]` returns an object with, in the language of the error, "+1 retain count"; i.e. an object the caller "owns" and which the caller must release.

When your code inserts an object into the array the array itself also takes ownership, i.e. does a retain. It does **not** take ownership from the caller, it is still left owning the block returned by `copy` and it is this ownership which is never relinquished which results in the leak, as the error states.

If you enable ARC it will take care of this and release the callers ownership of the block at the appropriate point.

Otherwise you can leave ARC off and insert a `release` call when the caller no longer requires the block (which still leaves the array with ownership).

HTH